# Geometry Dash won't open

Tags: geometry-dash

I was going to play *Geometry Dash* on Steam. When I tried to open it, the game said "**Running**" for a few seconds, and then it just reverted back to "**Play**".

What I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling
- Clearing the files completely (using Everything - Voidtools)
- Using compatibility settings
- Using the log.txt

And all it said was something like:

> (settings.cc) : version is not 1

And nothing worked.

Specs:

- Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics 3.00GHz
- RAM: 8 GB
- OS: Windows 10 Home (x64)

(Before, my *Geometry Dash* would work.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert, but this worked for me when I encountered this bug so I hope it helps.

Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `appdata`, then click `Local`. Go the the Geometry Dash folder, and delete `CCGameManager`, `CCGameManager2`, `CCLocalLevels`, and `CCLocalLevels2`.
When you open your game, it will reset some stuff like songs and levels. But once you log into your account, it should work fine.